# Ion-searchbar ícone à direita

Tags: ionic

Parece simples mas não encontrei nada.
Como posso colcoar o ícone do lado direito >>>>  e a barra de pesquisa ao lado esquerdo <<<  ?

```
   <ion-searchbar placeholder="Buscar" [(ngModel)]="queryText" 
   (ionInput)="filterProduto($event)" clearInput class="search">
   </ion-searchbar>
```

scss

```
    .search{

    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    left: 45%;
    top: 1%;  
    text-align: right;

    .searchbar-search-icon {
        background-image: url("../assets/imgs/ico_busca.svg")!important;
        width: 40px;  

      }
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente bem simples...  apenas adicionei left ao ícon em scss

```
.search{

    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    left: 45%;
    top: 1%;  
    background: transparent;
    max-width: 160px;

    .searchbar-search-icon {
        background-image: url("../assets/imgs/ico_busca.svg")!important;
        width: 30px;  
        left: 90px;
      }

}
```